# How can i split on a string

Tags: java, string, split

I have a .txt file that I browse through a bufferReader and I need to extract the last character from this String, I leave the line below

```html
<path
  action="m"
  text-mod="true"
  mods="true"
  kind="file">branches/RO/2021Align01/CO/DGSIG-DAO/src/main/java/eu/ca/co/vo/CsoorspeWsVo.java</path>
```

I have the following code that takes my entire line and sets it in a list, but I just need it Cs00rspeWsVo

```
while ((line = bufferdReader.readLine()) != null) {
  Excel4 excel4 = new Excel4();
  if (line.contains("</path>")) {
    int index1 = line.indexOf(">");
    int index2 = line.lastIndexOf("<");
    line = line.substring(index1, index2);
    excel4.setName(line);
    listExcel4.add(excel4);
  }
}
```

and I only want to extract Cs00rspeWsVo from here.
can anyone help me? thanks

Comment: The code you sent is not compiling, its missing a semilocon at the `index2` line. Please make sure to post the correct code and double check that there are no other issues.

Comment: The specific problem in your code here is that you are declaring `int index1` inside the scope of the `if` block, but then trying to reference it outside the if. That said, munging XML-ish data like this isn't necessarily the best approach: parse it properly to extract the data.

Comment: What your doing is quite hacky but honestly if you already go that approach, why not just search for the second to last index of `/` and then extract there. So substring from second to last `/` to last `<`, then you have it. `int lastSlash = text.lastIndexOf("/")`, then `int secondToLastSlash = text.lastIndexOf("/", lastSlash)`, then with ur existing `index2` and you have `text.substring(secondToLastSlash, index2)`. Or working with your current `line`, just `line.substring(line.lastIndexOf("/"))`.

Comment: I would suggest either substring from last '/' to last 'c', or use regex.

Comment: You could also interpret the path as `Path` and then use its high level methods. So something like `Path.of(line).getFileName()` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex groups to get it for example

```java
public static void main(String []args){
    String input = "<path\n" +
                "  action=\"m\"\n" +
                "  text-mod=\"true\"\n" +
                "  mods=\"true\"\n" +
                "  kind=\"file\">branches/RO/2021Align01/CO/DGSIG-DAO/src/main/java/eu/ca/co/vo/CsoorspeWsVo.java</path>\n";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("kind=\"file\">.+/(.+\\..+)</path>");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        String fileName = matcher.group(1);
        System.out.println(fileName);
    }
}
```

Output will be -> `CsoorspeWsVo.java`

and if you want the fill path change the regex to

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("kind=\"file\">(.+)</path>");
```

The output will be:

`branches/RO/2021Align01/CO/DGSIG-DAO/src/main/java/eu/ca/co/vo/CsoorspeWsVo.java`

And you can get name and extension in two groups for example

```
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("kind=\"file\">.+/(.+)\\.(.+)</path>");
```

And inside the if

```
String fileName = matcher.group(1);
String fileExtension = matcher.group(2);
```